# addRole using userManager doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.4

I'm trying to add roles to user when they are registering in this way:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->createUser();

$user_data = $request->get('user_profile');

$user->setUsername($user_data['rif']);
$user->setEmail($user_data['user']['email']);
$user->setPlainPassword($user_data['user']['password']);
$user->addRole("ROLE_USER");
$userManager->updateUser($user);
```

All works fine excepts that roles at DB is stored as `a:0:{}` and I can't find the error, can any give me some advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are trying to add the `ROLE_USER` role.

Have you tried adding another role?

The problem lies in..

<kbd>FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface</kbd>

```
const ROLE_DEFAULT = 'ROLE_USER';
const ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN = 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN';
```

<kbd>FOS\UserBundle\Model\User</kbd>

```
public function addRole($role)
{
    $role = strtoupper($role);
    if ($role === static::ROLE_DEFAULT) {
    // If supplied $role === ROLE_USER just return User object
        return $this;
    }

    if (!in_array($role, $this->roles, true)) {
        $this->roles[] = $role;
    }

    return $this;
}

....

/**
 * Returns the user roles
 *
 * @return array The roles
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = $this->roles;

    foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
        $roles = array_merge($roles, $group->getRoles());
    }

    // we need to make sure to have at least one role
    $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT;

    return array_unique($roles);
}
```

If you add the default role (`ROLE_USER`) it doesn't actually get added to the list of roles due to it being added, as default, to the roles in the `getRoles` method.

Answer (score 1):

If your remaining things works then your code line

```
 $user->addRole("ROLE_USER");
```

should be as

```
$user->setRoles(array("ROLE_USER"));
```

because in your User class(FOS\UserBundle\Model\User)

```
    public function setRoles(array $roles)
    {
      $this->roles = array();

      foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $this->addRole($role);
        }

       return $this;
      }
```

method is defined for setting roles and its value  should be in array format ..

Comment: In case you didn't notice, FOSUserBundle (as well as your copied code) uses `$this->addRole($role)` to add a role to the roles array. Setting the roles with an array would involve having to read all of the roles each time you wanted to add a role.

Comment: ya,u'r right, and if u want to fetch just entered role then in your child bundle user class this method should be overrided as "public function setRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }"

Comment: That is a unnecessary override. By changing it to just use `setRoles` as an array that means that to add a role you have to call `$roles = $user->getRoles(); $roles[] = 'NEW_ROLE'; $user->setRoles($roles)` rather than just `$user->addRole('NEW_ROLE')`.

Comment: but if it is  passed as direct ->setRoles($roles), then it gives error that "it should be compatible with "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User"'s setRoles(array $roles) method", because this child user class(my Bundle's User Class) has extended the "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User" class . and more if it is passed ->setRoles('ROLE_USER') then it gives error like "expected array value but it is string" ..

Comment: I understand that `setRoles()` needs to fit the parent but it's unnecessary to override it. `setRoles(array $roles)` works fine as it is but there is also an `addRoles($role)` methods. Neither of these methods need to be overwritten. In your version in your child model you are just removing the `addRole` part for no reason at all.

Comment: Ya, there is also a method addRole() , which is called in setRoles(array $roles) method . This override is in this special case , that if without overriding setRoles() method , we add role 'ROLE_CLIENT' then there is also a by default role 'ROLE_USER' , then after merging this user has now two roles 'ROLE_USER' and 'ROLE_CLIENT', but if i want only one current role 'ROLE_CLIENT' , then it's necessary to override the method setRoles(array $roles) as discussed above

Comment: Except that when you call `getRoles()` the role `ROLE_USER` is added by default (when GETTING the roles), the role `ROLE_USER` is never actually added to the roles array. If you wanted to not have `ROLE_USER` in your returned roles then you should override the `getRoles()` method rather than the `setRoles()`.

Comment: ya,now i do't know whether i m right or wrong, but the both method works same job. thanks a lot for updating my knowledge .., i think $user->addRole("ROLE_USER"); should work but do't know why it is not working as asked in above question ..

Answer (score 0):

In case you create your form like this :

```
            ->add('roles','collection', array(
                'label'     => 'Rôle',
                'type'      => 'choice',
                'options'   => array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'ROLE_USER'             => 'Client',
                        'ROLE_ADMIN'            => 'Admin',
                        'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'      => 'SuperAdmin',
                        'ROLE_TECHNICIEN'       => 'Technicien',
                        'ROLE_RESPONSABLE_PARC' => 'Responsable'
                    ),
                    'expanded'  => false,
                    'multiple' => false
                )
            ))
```

Change it like this :

```
    $builder->add('roles', 'choice', array(
                'label'     => 'Rôles',
                'choices' => array(
                    'ROLE_USER'             => 'Client',
                    'ROLE_ADMIN'            => 'Admin',
                    'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'      => 'SuperAdmin',
                    'ROLE_TECHNICIEN'       => 'Technicien ',
                    'ROLE_RESPONSABLE_PARC' => 'Responsable'
                ),
                'expanded'  => false,
                'multiple' => true,
            ))
```

Because role is just an array